# Trying to create a p:selectOneMenu and entities from a database

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I managed to retrieve all the information I need from database, but when I put it in  `<p:selectOneMenu>` using `<f:selectItems value="">` I get an empty `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

[image]

This is a snippet of my code :

my xhtml file:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel for="usernames" value="usernames "/>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="usernames" value="#{Jcalendar.THE_CHOSEN_ONE}">
        <f:selectItems value="Jcalendar.user_spinner_list"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panelGrid>
```

my JcalendarBeans.java file

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Jcalendar")
@SessionScoped
public class JcalendarBeans implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String THE_CHOSEN_ONE;

    public String getTHE_CHOSEN_ONE() {
        return THE_CHOSEN_ONE;
    }

    public void setTHE_CHOSEN_ONE(String tHE_CHOSEN_ONE) {
        THE_CHOSEN_ONE = tHE_CHOSEN_ONE;
    }

    List<JcalendarController> user_spinner_list = new ArrayList<JcalendarController>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        user_spinner_list = JcalendarDAO.AllUsarname_spinner();
    }
}
```

any help would be appropriated

Answer (score 1):

In your xhtml file make sure you add "()":

```
 <f:selectItems value="Jcalendar.user_spinner_list()"/>
```

Comment: I get values now but I do not know how to converted to string ?

Comment: This precisely does not appear to be an answer. If that list contains composite/complex objects, you need to explicitly tell JSF to use a specific property as an `itemLabel` and another property as an `itemValue` or you need to use a `java.util.Map<key, value>` (or `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap` depending upon the requirements) in which keys are inferred as option's labels and values are inferred as option's values (in the generated `<select>` HTML tag) - `<f:selectItems value="#{bean.map}"/>`.  (which in turn requires a converter to convert those objects to and from String).

Comment: well... this what i did !!!

    <p:selectOneMenu id="Users" value="#{Jcalendar.username}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{Jcalendar.user_spinner()}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: then 
public static List<String> AllUsarname_spinner() {
}